# SmartyCompilerException unknown tag "include"

Tags: php, smarty3

I've recently moved a website from a PHP 5.2 environment to 5.4.35.

The site uses Smarty 3.1 for templating and unfortunatley it's not a tool i'm familiar with. Since the big move we're getting unknown tag "include" errors.

I wondered if anyone in the community had come across this before?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/templates/index.html" on line 1 "<!--{include file="_header.html"}-->" unknown tag "include"' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/smarty3.1/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 617
```

I have tried searching the Smarty forums with little success. Does anyone have any idea what I need to look for?

Answer (score 0):

> IMPORTANT NOTICE
>
> {include_php} is deprecated from Smarty, use registered plugins to properly insulate presentation from the application code. As of Smarty 3.1 the {include_php} tags are only available from SmartyBC.

Source: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.php.tpl